# jQuery - tell when page has been scrolled to, and is viewing, a specific DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a one-page website, each different "page" is a different div. Each div is placed below one another, so only one div is viewable at time. I want to be able to tell when a user scrolls to, and is viewing, one of the divs, and based on which div ID alter the CSS of a correpsonding link in my navigation. Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: listen to the scroll event. When scroll top is x, do y.

Comment: i think this is what you want => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling, or at least some modification of it

Answer (score 3):

Check out this plugin - it does exactly what you described

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
    var allDivs = $("div");
    for(var i = allDivs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        if($(allDivs[i]).position().top < document.body.scrollTop + 100){
            $("span").text(allDivs[i].innerText);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AzMxG/